# Las URI segment is zero (/0) -> error DIsallowed characters

Tags: codeigniter

I tried to find a solution for this issue but nothing worked. When my REST api URI request is, ex. https://serverip/meeting/userlist/0

I always get the error "The URI you submitted has disallowed characters”. I have even tried to leave this parameter in the config file blank:

$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_-+';

But I get the same error.

Is not allowed to have a 0 at the end of the URI as unique content of that segment? Because I need that to retrieve user with id = 0.

Thanks a lot.

EDIT - SOLVED:

Hi Again,

finally I solved it. I found that long time ago we commented a check related to UTF8 encodig in URI.php

if ( ! empty($str) && ! empty($this->_permitted_uri_chars) && ! preg_match('/^['.$this->_permitted_uri_chars.']+$/i'.(UTF8_ENABLED ? 'u' : ''), $str))

And we only left the first condition. We had some code issues that seem not to reproduce after revert that comment. And /0 now works fine.

So sorry, at the end it was a problem related to our own modifications.

Thanks.

Comment: Set  $config['permitted_uri_chars'] variable as  'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-\='

Comment: Hi Paresh, same problem with that config. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

`$config['permitted_uri_chars']` is used as a PCRE character class pattern.

With the last character in there being a dash, it looks for a dash. However, when a dash is between two characters, it triggers a range search. So ... when you append the + (plus) sign after the dash, you get:

```
[_-+] // a range between underscore and plus in the ASCII table
```

You might be thinking "So what? Zeros are already allowed previously via 0-9", and you'd be correct, but that's not the problem. The problem is that the plus sign has a lower ASCII number than the underscore, and ranges don't work backwards, so `_-+` is invalid and triggers a PCRE compilation failure, which in turn means the entire check fails and nothing is actually allowed.

You would see this if you had `error_reporting` enabled and/or looked at the error logs.

This doesn't happen if you only append the plus sign to the default pattern - the dash is not only the last character, but also escaped with a backslash - as you'd have this instead:

```
[_\-+] // Underscore, dash and plus sign as individual characters; not a range
```

I guess you thought it was an actual character to be allowed and removed it. Just add it back:

```
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-+';
```